# R - Create a column with consecutive numbers and reset based on other column using mutate

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-columns, reset, dplyr

I am trying to use `mutate` to create a new variable `game_plus` in my `df`, which counts the number of days *since* an event occurred in another column `game` and resets every time the event occurs. For instance, the variable `game` in my `df` is binary and can take on either `"Game"` or `"Training"`. I was thinking to use a nested `ifelse` statement to generate the **following output**:

```
game         game_plus
Game             0
Training         1
Training         2
Training         3
Game             0
Training         1
Training         2
Game             0
Training         1
Training         2
Training         3
Training         4
```

I would also like to the **opposite** for a column `game_minus`, which essentially counts the number of days *before* an event, like the following.

```
game         game_plus      game_minus
Game             0              0
Training         1              3
Training         2              2
Training         3              1
Game             0              0
Training         1              2
Training         2              1 
Game             0              0
Training         1              4
Training         2              3
Training         3              2
Training         4              1
```

Can anybody assist with this? I know I can use `ifelse(game == "Game", 0,` but I am struggling to figure out how to incorporate the - **prior to or since the event occurred**- element into this ifelse statement. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

game_tbl <- 
tibble(game = c("Game",rep("Training", 3), "Game",rep("Training", 2),"Game",rep("Training", 4)))


game_tbl  %>% 
  mutate(period = cumsum(game == "Game")) %>% ## which rows belong to one game period 
  group_by(period, game) %>% 
  mutate(game_plus = case_when(game == "Game" ~ 0L , TRUE ~ row_number())) %>%
  group_by(period) %>%  
  mutate(units = n() ) %>% ## how many rows per  game period
  mutate(game_minus =  case_when(game == "Game" ~ 0L, TRUE ~  units - row_number() + 1L )) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(game, game_plus, game_minus)
```

Basically you need to work with **group_by** and **row_number**.
**row_number** adds the number of each row. In combination with **group_by** it coutns through the rows for each group. I added the helper variable **period** to identify all rows that belong to one game-period (from game to last training). Thus, **row_number** will count rows through each game-period for game == "Game" and game == "Training". I also added the helper varible **units** to count the rows for each game-period.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `data.table` the gist here is breaking up the data into sections using `n_games`. Then `data.table` has a built in way to essentially get row numbers using `.I` and so if we break up the data into each section we can take the row numbers in reverse to get the count down. The last thing left is to assign each game day a value of 0 instead of the number of days until the next game.

```r
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(game = c("Game",rep("Training", 3), "Game",rep("Training", 2),"Game",rep("Training", 4)))
## Create an indicator for if a day has a game
dt[,game_ind := ifelse(game == 'Game', 1, 0)]
## Use the indicators to break up the data into groups by taking the cumulative sum of games
dt[,n_games := cumsum(game_ind)]
## .SD[,.I] gets the row number for each group of n_games, rev makes it so that it's 
## counting down instead of up
dt[,game_minus := rev(unlist(.SD[,.I])), by = n_games]
## Set game days to 0
dt[game == 'Game', game_minus := 0]

dt
#>         game game_ind n_games game_minus
#>  1:     Game        1       1          0
#>  2: Training        0       1          3
#>  3: Training        0       1          2
#>  4: Training        0       1          1
#>  5:     Game        1       2          0
#>  6: Training        0       2          2
#>  7: Training        0       2          1
#>  8:     Game        1       3          0
#>  9: Training        0       3          4
#> 10: Training        0       3          3
#> 11: Training        0       3          2
#> 12: Training        0       3          1

## If you want to clean up
dt[,c('game_ind', 'n_games') := NULL]

head(dt)
#>        game game_minus
#> 1:     Game          0
#> 2: Training          3
#> 3: Training          2
#> 4: Training          1
#> 5:     Game          0
#> 6: Training          2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>